# Parameter format not correct -

Tags: python

```py
import os

USER_NAME = os.getlogin()
file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME

os.system('attrib h+ ' + bat_path + '\Run.py')
```

When i run this i get this error:

> Parameter format not correct -

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the corresponding format string for `USER_NAME`
Perhaps you are looking for something like

```py
bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\{}'.format(USER_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i still get the same error

Comment: ill try something else thanks for your help!

Comment: Is you code named `file.py`? If `bat_path` is correct, the error stems from the file Run.py